# bibtex package option date

Tags: bibtex

i want to make my bibliography to follow the chem-acs style.
So i use bibtex style=chem-acs, the output looks almost correctly except the formate of the date. It uses somehow the month and the year, i want it to use only the year. I looked up the package options and found the option date=... with possibilities like "short, comp, long,..and year" So it looks perfect, i need only the year! But once i use date=year i get errors when i compile it :( all other options for date work fine...
Can anybody give me a hint why bibtex is behaving like this?

thanks!

Comment: Do you have the dates in your `.bib` file (most people don't bother)? If so, are you using Biber or BibTeX?

Comment: Yes, in the `.bib` file are months, since they are imported from some sources. I use `backend=bibtex` in my file. The documentation on bibtex shows `date=year` as an option, but even the minimal example will not build with this option.